# AdMob banner ads not showing in Xamarin.iOS apps

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, admob

I know that this exact question has been asked hundreds of time, but every user has a different problem and I have already tried many solutions, not getting anywhere.

The good thing is that banner test ads (like the one here: [LINK](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)) are showing correctly… and I have registered a Unit banner in AdMob (without connecting FireBase, yet)

This is my code, taken from various samples in the internet… it's a pretty standard code pattern for everyone of them:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAd"
         xmlns:localIOS="clr-namespace:TestAd.iOS"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestAd.ViewModels"
         x:Class="TestAd.MainPage">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:AppViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<StackLayout>
    <Grid …>
    </Grid>

    <localIOS:AdMobView AdUnitId="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX"/>
    <ListView ...>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

**AdView**

```
public class AdMobView : View
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty AdUnitIdProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
               nameof(AdUnitId),
               typeof(string),
               typeof(AdMobView),
               string.Empty);

    public string AdUnitId
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(AdUnitIdProperty);
        set => SetValue(AdUnitIdProperty, value);
    }
}
```

**AdViewRenderer**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdMobView), typeof(AdMobViewRenderer))]
namespace AppReminderIOS.iOS
{
public class AdMobViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdMobView, BannerView>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdMobView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null)
        {
            SetNativeControl(CreateBannerView());
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(BannerView.AdUnitID))
            Control.AdUnitID = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX"; //Even tried: "Element.AdUnitId;"
    }

    private BannerView CreateBannerView()
    {
        var bannerView = new BannerView(AdSizeCons.SmartBannerPortrait)
        {
            AdUnitID = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX", //Even tried: "Element.AdUnitId,"
            RootViewController = GetVisibleViewController()
        };

        bannerView.LoadRequest(GetRequest());

        Request GetRequest()
        {
            var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
            return request;
        }

        return bannerView;
    }

    private UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
    {
        var windows = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows;
        foreach (var window in windows)
        {
            if (window.RootViewController != null)
            {
                return window.RootViewController;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Google.MobileAds.MobileAds.Configure("ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~XXXXXXXX");

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```

This is the main code… what do you think?
Could there be a problem with my AdMob account?
Test ads are showing correctly AND they even refresh thereselves as I rotate the device… so I don't know what to think.

Thank you for you kindness in helping me.

Comment: You means that only change the AdUnitID(Test ads) ,it works fine?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT    Exactly: just changing the Ad ID in the MainPage.xaml to the test one, makes it working correctly and showing succesfully the test banner.    I even created a second Ad ID for the same app, but nothing changed…    I don't really know what it could be...

Comment: If you have recently created an AD unit ID(in 24 hours), it may take some time and several AD requests to build up AD resources. Because of this, you may not immediately see the actual presentation. You should see more consistent results when your application requests multiple times. Please note that the test AD runs through the same channels as the actual AD. If the test AD returns, your application is communicating correctly with the network.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT     You were right, I just saw a real banner ad showing up in my app!     The problem is that it appeared only once and for the rest of the time the ad space is blank... how should I optimize it in order to fill it all the time?

Comment: Did it  fill  all the time when you use the test  unit ID?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem about ads not showing in Xamarin.iOS apps.You can mark it as answer so that other developer can find answer easilier when they have similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently created an AD unit ID(in 24 hours), it may take some time and several AD requests to build up AD resources. Because of this, you may not immediately see the actual presentation. You should see more consistent results when your application requests multiple times. Please note that the test AD runs through the same channels as the actual AD. If the test AD returns, your application is communicating correctly with the network.